# Is it possible to convert an element of a char arrary into a const char?

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I dont want to covert the char array into const char array, but to make an element constant after it has got a particular value. This, I require for a tic tac toe game. When a grid has got the value of X or O, it needs to be unchangeable, to ensure that players can't put X and O on a grid which has been taken.

I searched about it(on google and stackoverflow), but so far it seems impossible. Is this approach wrong? I dont want to alter the whole program to overcome this problem, so I need some other way to ensure that players dont change a grid after its taken.

Comment: `const` is a compile-time feature.  It sounds like you need to prevent something from changing based on run-time input.

Comment: Yes exactly @aschepler. But how do I do it?

Comment: What type of array are you talking about? Plain old-data C-Style arrays? Something like `char squares[9]` ?

Comment: It is impossible to use the `const` feature this way, because since it is a compile-time feature, you need to know what will be `const` when you compile the code. It would be possible to make a custom `Cell` class with the only mutators checking for whether the character is null, but that would probably be overkill; a better solution would probably be to just do the run-time checks to make sure you never change the value once it’s set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` is made for developers. It just says to the compiler that a value is unchangeable, allowing the compiler to make some optimizations and protecting from programmer errors.

In your case, you must write your own code to protect your field. For example, you can initialize each field with the space symbol (`' '`) and, before changing the cell's value, check the current value… allowing a change only if the value is the space symbol.

Comment: Please do not randomly omit words

Comment: It's just my terrible english :)

Comment: Thanks! I put cin(that gets the grid no. which is to be changed) inside a loop that terminates only when that grid is neither X nor O.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to make some elements of an array const while leaving others mutable (i.e., non-const). Instead, consider making an object for each piece that includes methods to lock the value. Consider, for example, the following class outline:

```
class Piece {
    public:
        Piece();
        void LockValue();
        void SetValue(char c);
        char GetValue();
        bool GetIsLocked();

    private:
        char value;
        bool isLocked;
};
```

Now you can implement SetValue in such a way that it:

- Checks the value of isLocked before it attempts to change anything
- Sets isLocked to true after the first call.

Now you can create an array of these objects and use them to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks! It seems a neat way but instead i implemented the idea of devalone. Was easier for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a background bool grid which tracks whether the position is already used up or not... If a player has already used it, it will be true otherwise the position will be false and anyone can use it.

```
//general code
char grid[3][3];
bool alreadyUsed[3][3] = {{false,false,false},{false,false,false},{false,false,false}};

if(alreadyUsed[playerChoiceX][playerChoiceY] == false)
{
    grid[playerChoiceX][playerChoiceY] = playerTurn;   //playerTurn is X or O
    alreadyUsed[playerChoiceX][playerChoice] = true;
}
else
    cout << "Position already used, select another position.\n";
```

Edit: I know this does not answer your question but it will help you complete the game. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, thats a nice idea!

Comment: To be honest, you don't even need a bool alreadyUsed 2D array.

if(!(grid[playerChoiceX][playerChoiceY] == 'X' || grid[playerChoiceX][playerChoiceY] == 'O'))
    grid[playerChoiceX][playerChoiceY] = playerTurn;   //playerTurn is X or O

Comment: Yeah! I did exactly that. :)